# Gatsby: How to handle undefined fields in siteMetadata?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I want to build a site header based on having defined a `logo` field or not (if it is not defined it will be used the site title instead).

**gatsby-config.js:**

```js
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Hello Web',
    logo: '/images/logo.png'
  }
}
```

**query:**

```js
const query = graphql`
  {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
        logo
      }
    }
  }
```

The above works fine, but if I remove the `logo` field the [build breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fztoh.png).

I read the Schema Customization section on Gatsby documentation, but I didn't find anything that apply (am I missing something?).

My current solution is to set `logo` to some "dummy content". Although it works, it's clearly not an elegant solution and have some drawbacks as the project grows.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [create types in this blog post.](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-03-18-releasing-new-schema-customization/#createtypes) and [fixing fields in the the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#fixing-field-types).

> `createTypes` can be used to define, fix, or extend a Gatsby GraphQL type that represents some of your app’s data. Think of it like an escape hatch to politely inform Gatsby of your data’s shape.

Gatsby infers the schema based on the data it has available at build time. If you try to query for a field that doesn't exist, you will get a build error.

With `createTypes` you can tell gatsby that the `logo` field is a nullable `String` on the `SiteSiteMetadata` type. Now if the field is not found in your data source, you will get a null value for it, but gatsby can successfully build.

```
// gatsby-node.js

exports.sourceNodes = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions
  const typeDefs = `
    type SiteSiteMetadata implements Node {
      logo: String
    }
  `
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

> Note that the rest of the fields (title, description, author) don’t have to be provided, they will still be handled by Gatsby’s type inference.

[image]